# Is there any way to ssh into a docker machine from another computer on the same network

Tags: docker

I have 2 PCs.
1 is Running windows 10 with docker and 2 docker machines which are as below:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker-machine ls
NAME  ACTIVE DRIVER   STATE    URL                    SWARM   DOCKER     ERRORS
vm1   *      hyperv   Running  tcp://2.22.8.102:2376          v18.09.2
vm2   -      hyperv   Running  tcp://2.22.8.103:2376          v18.09.2
```

I run the alpine image both the machines and and then use putty on the same computer to ssh into the docker machines which i am able to do so.

Now i just want to do ssh to these docker machines from my other computer and I am not finding any way to do so.

Can any one let me know whether it is possible and if so how can i be able to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: You say you're able to connect via SSH with Putty on your primary machine... Why not just connect the same way on the secondary machine?

Comment: I tried but I am not able to connect. The ssh connectivity is working fine from the host machine itself (where docker is hosted). But when i try from other physical machine, it is getting timed out...

Answer (score 0):

You should have ssh running in the machine where you need to ssh into. 
You can find more information on how to achieve inter docker communications
[here](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/#communication-between-containers)

Comment: I am not looking for inter-docker communication. I am looking to connect to a docker machine from another computer. 
There are 2 windows physical machines ....  win1 and win2...

win1 ( runs hyper-v with docker and runs 2 docker machines - vm1 and vm2 ). 

On win1, i use putty and ssh to any of the docker machines either vm1 or vm2 and it connects which implies that ssh is running on the docker machines...

On win2, there is only putty (no docker) and i want to connect to vm1 or vm2 using ssh. 

If it is possible, please let me know.